# Dynamic image with variable as a name

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to display an image when i have variable from array (arr[r1]) which matches the name of the picture.
I tried using this but it didnt work:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+arr[r1], "drawable", getPackageName())));
```

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: define "didn't work". format.

Comment: imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/"+arr[r1], "drawable", getPackageName())));

Comment: what is the value of arr[r1]?

Answer (score 1):

```
String filePath = getActivity().getFileStreamPath("myimage.png").getAbsolutePath();

img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/"+arr[r1], "drawable", getPackageName())));
```

with

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(arr[r1], "drawable", getPackageName())));
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

this work fine for me

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/ic_launcher", "drawable", getPackageName())));
```

for your case use this

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/"+arr[r1], "drawable", getPackageName())));
```